Minecraft CC Tweaked Mod: Why does it appears that the turtle is skipping lines of code?
I am using the CC:Tweaked Minecraft Mod to attempt to automate crafting of stuff I need a lot of for other mods, and it uses lua. With the particular way the Turtles (robots) work, they need the component items inserted in certain slots in their inventory, set up like the normal crafting grid. To do this I've set up multiple chests around it and wrote a function to tell it what chest it needs to get the item for each slot from. From what I can tell, that part of the function works properly.
But when I run the program and input the directions of the chest, it then gets stuck on the while loop that's meant to make it wait for the item it needs if it isn't already in the chest, despite the item being there. On observation, the turtle doesn't even attempt to collect the item, it just jumps straight to the else line of that while loop in perpetuity without doing anything else.
The full code is here. I know it's probably poorly written since I wrote it while half asleep in 2 hours, but I'm more worried about it functioning than form since it's just a personal use thing.


On=1

Item1=false

Item2=false

Item3=false

Item4=false

Item5=false

Item6=false

Item7=false

Item8=false

Item9=false

Slot1=turtle.getItemCount(1)

Slot2=turtle.getItemCount(2)

Slot3=turtle.getItemCount(3)

Slot4=turtle.getItemCount(4)

Slot5=turtle.getItemCount(5)

Slot6=turtle.getItemCount(6)

Slot7=turtle.getItemCount(7)

Slot8=turtle.getItemCount(8)

Slot9=turtle.getItemCount(9)

MaterialLocation1= "front"

MaterialLocation2= "front"

MaterialLocation3= "front"

MaterialLocation4= "front"

MaterialLocation5= "front"

MaterialLocation6= "front"

MaterialLocation7= "front"

MaterialLocation8= "front"

MaterialLocation9= "front"



function getMaterialLocation(SelectedSlot)

    
    Complete=false

    

    while Complete == false do

        print("Please type the chest to use for slot ", SelectedSlot, "    Front Left Right Back Up Down      If the slot is empty type 'empty'.")

        Location=read()

        Location=string.lower(Location)



        if Location == "front" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="front"       

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="front"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="front"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

    

        elseif Location == "left" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="left"        

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="left"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="left"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

    

        elseif Location == "right" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="right"       

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="right"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="right"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

    

        elseif Location == "back" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="back"        

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="back"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="back"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

    

        elseif Location == "up" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="up"      

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="up"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="up"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

    

        elseif Location == "down" then

            if selectedSlot == 1 then

                MaterialLocation1="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 2 then

                MaterialLocation2="down"        

            elseif selectedSlot == 3 then

                MaterialLocation3="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 4 then

                MaterialLocation4="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 5 then

                MaterialLocation5="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 6 then

                MaterialLocation6="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 7 then

                MaterialLocation7="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 8 then

                MaterialLocation8="down"

            elseif selectedSlot == 9 then

                MaterialLocation9="down"

            end

        

            print("Slot ", SelectedSlot, " is ", Location)

            Complete=true

        

        elseif Location == "empty" then

            print(SelectedSlot, " is empty.")

            Complete=true

    

        else

            print("Try again, Fuckboy.")

        end

    end

end



function pullFront()

    turtle.suck(1)

end



function pullLeft()

    turtle.turnLeft()

    turtle.suck(1)

    turtle.turnRight()

end



function pullRight()

    turtle.turnRight()

    turtle.suck(1)

    turtle.turnLeft()

end



function pullBack()

    turtle.turnLeft()

    turtle.turnLeft()

    turtle.suck(1)

    turtle.turnLeft()

    turtle.turnLeft()

end



function pullUp()

    turtle.suckUp(1)

end



function pullDown()

    turtle.suckDown(1)

end

    

function drop()

    turtle.drop()

end



function craft()

    turtle.craft()

    item1=false

    item2=false

    item3=false

    item4=false

    item5=false

    item6=false

    item7=false

    item8=false

    item9=false

    drop()

    print(Done)



end



function getDirection(SelectedSlot)

    if SelectedSlot == 1 then

        if MaterialLocation1 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation1 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation1 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation1 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation1 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation1 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item1=true          

        end         



    elseif SelectedSlot == 2 then

        if MaterialLocation2 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation2 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation2 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation2 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation2 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation2 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item2=true      

        end



    elseif SelectedSlot == 3 then

        if MaterialLocation3 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation3 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation3 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation3 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation3 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation3 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item3=true          

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 4 then

        if MaterialLocation4 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation4 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation4 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation4 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item4=true      

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 5 then

        if MaterialLocation5 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation5 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item5=true      

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 6 then

        if MaterialLocation6 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation6 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item6=true          

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 7 then

        if MaterialLocation7 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation7 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation7 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation7 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation7 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation7 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item7=true  

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 8 then

        if MaterialLocation8 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation8 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation8 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation8 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation8 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation8 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item8=true

        end

        

    elseif SelectedSlot == 9 then

        if MaterialLocation9 == "front" then

            pullFront()

        elseif MaterialLocation9 == "left" then

            pullLeft()

        elseif MaterialLocation9 == "right" then

            pullRight()

        elseif MaterialLocation9 == "back" then

            pullBack()

        elseif MaterialLocation9 == "up" then

            pullUp()

        elseif MaterialLocation9 == "down" then

            pullDown()

        else

            Item9=true

        end

    end

end



function gatherMats()

    print ("Crafting...")

    

    select(1)

    while item1 == false do

        getDirection(1)

        Slot1=turtle.getItemCount(1)

        if Slot1 == 1 then

            Item1=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 1")

        end

    end

    

    select(2)

    while Item2 == false do

        getDirection(2)

        Slot2=turtle.getItemCount(2)

        if Slot2 == 1 then

            Item2=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 2")

        end

    end

        

            select(3)

    while Item3 == false do

        getDirection(3)

        Slot3=turtle.getItemCount(3)

        if Slot3 == 1 then

            Item3=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 3")

        end

    end



    select(5)

    while Item4 == false do

        getDirection(4)

        Slot4=turtle.getItemCount(4)

        if Slot4 == 1 then

            Item4=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 4")

        end

    end

        

    select(6)

    while Item5 == false do

        getDirection(2)

        Slot5=turtle.getItemCount(5)

        if Slot5 == 1 then

            Item5=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 5")

        end

    end

        

    select(7)

    while Item6 == false do

        getDirection(6)

        Slot6=turtle.getItemCount(6)

        if Slot6 == 1 then

            Item1=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 6")

        end     

    end

        

    select(9)

    while Item7 == false do

        getDirection(7)

        Slot6=turtle.getItemCount(7)

        if Slot7 == 1 then

            Item1=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 7")

        end

    end

        

    select(10)

    while Item8 == false do

        getDirection(8)

        Slot8=turtle.getItemCount(8)

        if Slot8 == 1 then

            Item8=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 8")

        end

    end

        

    select(11)

    while Item9 == false do

        getDirection(9)

        Slot9=turtle.getItemCount(9)

        if Slot9 == 1 then

            Item9=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 9")

        end

    end

end



function main()

    Working=true

    getMaterialLocation(1)

    getMaterialLocation(2)

    getMaterialLocation(3)

    getMaterialLocation(4)

    getMaterialLocation(5)

    getMaterialLocation(6)

    getMaterialLocation(7)

    getMaterialLocation(8)

    getMaterialLocation(9)



    while Working == true do

        gatherMats()

        craft()

    end

end



main()


The point it seems to get stuck on is here

function gatherMats()

    print ("Crafting...")

    

    select(1)

    while item1 == false do

        getDirection(1)

        Slot1=turtle.getItemCount(1)

        if Slot1 == 1 then

            Item1=true

        else

            print("Waiting for input in slot 1")

        end

    end



It just seems to skip the getDirection() function entirely so it never attempts to get the item to break the while loop, just endlessly printing the "waiting on input" message.
From what I see, even if the MaterialLocation variables were getting set incorrectly, it would still break out of the while loop because the else argument of the material location changes the condition variable for that loop.

Item1=true --> item1=true; or maybe it's the other way around: while item1 --> while Item1. In any case, you seem to have a typo.

In craft() the item variables are lowercase, but elsewhere they seem to be uppercase. "I'm more worried about it functioning than form...." This is one of many reasons that you should be concerned about writing reasonably clean code with better style: better style should help you avoid some types of bugs, like this one.

Ah sorry. I had noticed that typo in game but forgot to fix it in the pastebin I pulled it into the game from. I have fixed that typo before asking this question. Apologies.

Figured it out. Short answer, I just commented out the function that asks to input directions of the chests and just edited the variables myself for each different turtle. I guess the MaterialLocation variables were not getting set correctly for some reason so it was just using the default I set when I declared the variable. But this also makes it so I don't have to manually start the program again if the turtle gets unloaded, so honestly it's an improvement.
That and fixing a number of typos that were definitely made in my half asleep stupor/forgetting to change them when copying the same lines of code 9 times.
